# Points where $z^2\ln(z)$ is differentiable - Cauchy-Riemann the only way?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

As the title says, I'm wondering how to figure out where $$z^2\ln(z)$$ is complex differentiable and I'm wondering if there is a quicker way than breaking it into it's real and imaginary components and applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start with: the product of differentiable functions is differentiable.  Now, what branch of the logarithm are you calling $\ln$, or are you regarding this as a multi-valued function?  Do you know where it is/isn't differentiable?

Comment: Ah of course, of course, thanks for the help!